# How do I logon to webpage using python ansdselenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('945412')
print 'username entered'
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('mns347')
print 'password entered'
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
print 'submit'
```

but it is throwing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SS\Desktop\python-mp\sele_sample.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('945412')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"username"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Comment: Either id value is wrong or element is not loaded. You can add explicit wait to wait for element to be loaded.

Comment: Which answer is working. Please accept the answer by clicking on tick which is working.

Comment: @ChintamaniManjare none of them worked

Answer (score 1):

You can add explicit wait to wait for element to be loaded.

```
username= WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
 )
username.send_keys('945412')
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any mistake in your code. But according to your error message, there is no field with the id username.

Please make sure that there really is a field with the id username on your website.

As an example, githubs username field is defined as follows

```
<input name="login" id="login_field" class="form-control input-block" tabindex="1" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
```

In this case you would have to adapt your code to this. This would look like this

```
driver.find_element_by_id('login_field').send_keys('945412')
```

Because the field contains id="login_field"

Comment: it is also this error on command prompt                error in dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc on line 510

Comment: There are two things I could think of right now:

First, the website may not be fully loaded yet. To test this you could insert a `sleep` after `browser.get`

Second, the website reads the login in an iframe, so it is no longer found in this context. To test this, go up the dome and search for an iframe tag.

Comment: If it is an iframe, you can switch to the iframe using the following code
`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("iframe_id"))`

Comment: sleep is working fine which implies that the browser is uploaded correctly and the second command for iframe is also showing the same error

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I assume your code still fails after the sleep? And are you able to reproduce the error on a simple page, only containing the input fields within a form?

Answer (score 1):

```
import the by module and try this instead,

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
element = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="username")
element.send_keys('945412')
use wait like below, if the above code doesn't work username= WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
 );
username.send_keys('945412.')
```

Comment: it is also this error on command prompt                                                              error in dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc on line 510 –

Answer (score 1):

You need to install chromedriver and chrome. You can change these settings for other browsers if you want. This work fine for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

browser.get('<login_url>')

username = browser.find_element_by_name("<username_name_tag>")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("<password_name_tag>")

username.send_keys("<username>")
password.send_keys("<password>")

browser.find_element_by_id("<login_button_id>").click()
```

Comment: it is still not working and is also showing error on cmd prompt:                                           error in dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc on line 510

Comment: Is the latest version of chromedriver and chrome installed. @Shreya